# Is acceleration necessary to define force?

Tags: forces, momentum

A car is moving with a constant velocity. If it hits a wall, will it apply force on the wall?
My doubt is that if there is no acceleration, there should be no force.

Answer (score 4):

There is acceleration. The car *decelerates*, accelerating backwards, when it hits the wall, and either the wall breaks and accelerates or the *earth* accelerates by some tiny bit as the equal and opposite reaction.

The situation is complicated somewhat by the fact that the car is being crushed and the wall is being damaged, consuming some of the energy of the impact. There is however a perfectly clear notion of acceleration here, it’s just a tad bit more subtle than in many typical physics class examples.

Comment: [1/2] Sorry to bother you after 2 years and 9 months again. :) I have further doubts about this question. Deceleration is simply a negative form of acceleration. Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity with respect to time. Velocity cannot change without force if the motion isn't circular, and in this scenario, it's not circular motion. The wall cannot exert force on the car if the car doesn't exert force on the wall, and in this case, the car is moving at a constant velocity. So, how is the velocity actually changing here without force and without circular motion?

Comment: [2/2] Suppose that we are doing this experiment inside a computer algorithm model with Physics laws. Not in real life.

Comment: Smashing into walls and constant velocity don’t really go together. At the moment the car hits the wall, either the assumption of constant velocity is broken with the sudden deceleration of the car or the wall itself is broken by the continued motion of the car. If you run the math, the only way the car would actually have a constant velocity all the way through the wall (rather than some of the velocity being imparted to the wall) is if either its mass is infinite relative to that of the wall or if you perfectly apply just enough acceleration to keep the car from slowing down

Comment: "constant velocity is broken with the sudden deceleration of the car". It's very confusing. Deceleration needs the velocity change which is only possible with Newton's second law (that is if wall applies the force). But according to Newton's third law, wall cannot apply force on the car since the car's change in velocity is zero. So, physically, what's going on here and how all the Newton's three laws working here?

Comment: The notion of “constant velocity” is a convenient fiction we use in physics classes to make the math simpler. Real-world objects change velocity whenever they hit or pass through something, and that something “pushes” back on them. In this case, the collision with the wall causes the car to no longer be moving with constant velocity. If, for the sake of argument, you wanted to construct a hypothetical situation where the velocity of the car stays as constant as possible all the way through the collision, you’d need either the lightest, most fragile possible wall, or the heaviest possible car

Answer (score 1):

The link between the forces acting on a body of mass $m$ and its acceleration, $\vec a$ is this:

$$\sum \vec F= m \vec a$$
in which $\sum \vec F$ is the vector sum of all the forces acting on the body, sometimes called the *resultant force*.

As the car hits the wall much the largest force acting on the car is that from the wall. This force dominates $\sum \vec F$ so the car has a very large acceleration in the direction of the force (that is 'outwards" from the wall). Call it a *de*celeration if you like.

I assume that your concern is that the wall experiences a huge force from the car but doesn't accelerate noticeably (assuming that the wall isn't demolished by the impact). But it is the *resultant* force that gives acceleration, and the wall is, we assume on firm foundations. These foundations exert a force on the wall that is very nearly equal and opposite to that from the car. If the foundations are unable to exert this force, then the wall will accelerate, in other words it will topple over.

It is, in my opinion, an oversimplification to define a force in general as that which gives a body an acceleration. It is *resultant force* that does this.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheEnvironmentalist already pointed out, the car will decelerate when it is brought to a stop after impacting the wall.

Now, if you know the stopping distance $d$ of the car (the distance its center of mass moves between initial contact with the wall and when it stops) and its mass $m$ and its velocity $v$ just prior to impact, you can calculate the average force $F_{ave}$ the wall exerts stopping the car using the work energy theorem which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy ($mv^{2}/2$).

$$W_{net}=F_{ave}d=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is acceleration (deceleration). When the car hits the wall it either stops or goes back. Anyway the velocity changes so does momentum. As rate of change of momentum is defined as force there is force acting on the wall as well as car(third law of motion).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A force can exist without causing any acceleration. In this case the there are multiple forces acting some of which cancel out. Therefore not all forces will cause acceleration

So technically speaking, forces are independent of acceleration